# Delete dynamically added table row - react js

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am adding table rows to a table dynamically. Here how it looks in the UI:

[image: Sample screenshot]

Here is the logic I am using to create a new row:

I have a state variable `this.state = ({rows: []})`

on the "Insert" button click I am doing:

```
addNewRow = () => {
        this.setState({rows: this.state.rows.concat([{}])});
    }
```

In my `render()` I have the below code:

```
const rows = this.state.rows.map((item, id) => {
            return(
                <tr key={id}>
                    <td>Something</td>
                    <td>Something</td>
                    <td>Something</td>
                    <td>Something</td>
                    <td><Button onClick={(event) => this.removeRow(event, id)}>Delete</Button></td>
                </tr>
            );
        });
```

and, obviously my final table code looks like the below:

```
<Table borderless>
    <tbody>
       {rows}
    </tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
       <td>
        <Button onClick={() => {this.addNewRow()}} size="sm" className="float-left">insert</Button>
       </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</Table>
```

Here is my `removeRow` function:

```
removeRow = (event, id) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = this.state.rows.indexOf(id);
        this.state.rows.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({rows: this.state.rows});
    }
```

The entire code works. I have changed variable names and stripped unwanted codes from them, but this is to give an idea of how I designed it.

My problem is when I click on "Delete" button, it always removes the last item in the row, not the item row which I have clicked. How to fix this?

I googled about the same, and I found few examples, to be honest, I felt they are complex and so I decided to go on my own way.

Please advise what need to be done to fix this issue.

Comment: did you try my edited  answer ?

Answer (score 1):

**Never Mutate the state directly in React:**

You need to do it this way:

```
removeRow=(event,id)=>{  
  var array = [...this.state.rows]; // make a new copy of array instead of mutating the same array directly. 
  var index = array.findIndex(x => x.id===id); //find the index of item which matches the id passed to the function
  array.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({people: array});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks noted. But this still doesn't fix my issue. It still delete's the last row instead of current clicked row.

Comment: i have edited my answer. the problem might be in finding the Index of item. see i have changed the logic for finding the index

Comment: Yes, I did. Good catch on finding that indexOf is causing the first issue. You are right. That line in my code always returns -1. Your code of using findIndex is perfect. It finds the index fine, but still at the end react removes the last added element :(

Comment: can you add your minimal code to sandbox it will be very easy to find the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using an array index as a key for `<tr>` element.

React uses the `key` to identity what to insert, or delete from existing DOM tree.

Please use any other unique identifier, for instance, `Date.now()` as a key, and save this key as a part of `rows` state.

```
addNewRow = () => {
  const { rows } = this.state
  this.setState({
    rows: [
      ...rows,
      {
        id: Date.now(),
      },
    ],
  })
}

render() {
   const rows = this.state.rows.map((item, index) => (
     <tr key={item.id}>
     </tr>
   ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me a sample setting `Date.now()` saving it to the part of `rows`. I am confused where it should be done and what will be the changes having to my removeRow function.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using `.map()` wrong.

You'll need to pass **`item`** like this:

```
<td><Button onClick={(event) => this.removeRow(event, item)}>Delete</Button></td>
```

You were passing index of the array as `id`. Because, second parameter of `array.map` operator is the **index** of that element in the array.

Do this instead:

```
removeRow = (event,item) => {  
  var array = [...this.state.rows]; // make a new copy of array instead of mutating the same array directly. 
  var index = array.indexOf(item)
  array.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({people: array});
  }
```

Comment: what are you doing with `item`  in `removeRow` and where are getting the `id` from ?

Comment: Item is being passed. Of which OP wants to finds the index of.

Comment: Makes sense. But still it removes the last item, instead of the clicked item.

Comment: Where did you logged it?